# Entity Framework 4.1 To know the which Foreign Key constraint is violated during deletion

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have started using Entity Framework 4.1 with Code first. I really love this over the previous ado.net techniques.

I have a very simple situation in which there is a department table and an employee table in database. Each employee belongs to a department and a department has got many employees. The business rule is : While, deleting a department, if there are any associated employees, it should not allow deletion. I can write a small method just before deletion and check the dependancy. However, since my project is a much complex one with more than 300 db tables, I hate to do this. The relationships gets changed frequently which results in lot of changes in all the delete methods of the project.

In ado.net, in similar situations, I used to parse the exception thrown and get the name of the particular Foreign key constraint which was violated. Based on the name of the violated FK constraint, I used to give appropriate error message to client. This technique worked well even in a fairly large project with more than 150 tables.

How do I do a similar thing in EF ? How do I get which FK is violated when SaveChanges() is called ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `Message` of the inner most exception(usually its a `SqlException`). Then you can extract the FK name from that string and check which FK is violated.